# Popup slider in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to create a pop up slider (or any widget) in tkinter python?

like this [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/popup-menu-in-tkinter/) but with slider instead?

it should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGW8o.png) (ignore the background), preferably on top of the button clicked for pop up

**Note**
I'm looking for a POP up, so please don't suggest that I change the current layout to add a slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. However, you have to build it yourself with a frame. This is a perfect example of where `place` is superior to `grid` and `pack` since the placement of the widget won't affect other widgets.

The key is to create a frame that is a child of the root window so that the frame will appear above other widgets. Then it's just a matter of calling `place` and using the `in_` parameter to specify that the frame placement should be relative to the button.

Here's a basic example that is implemented as a class:

```
import tkinter as tk

class PopupSliderButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.configure(command=self.toggle)
        self.sliderframe = tk.Frame(self.winfo_toplevel(), bd=1, relief="sunken", bg="#ebebeb")
        self.slider = tk.Scale(self.sliderframe, from_=0, to_=100, background=self.sliderframe.cget("background"))
        self.slider.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=4, pady=4)

    def get(self):
        return self.slider.get()

    def toggle(self):
        if self.sliderframe.winfo_viewable():
            self.sliderframe.place_forget()
        else:
            self.sliderframe.place(in_=self, x=0, y=-4, anchor="sw")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x300")

text = tk.Text(root, bd=1, relief="sunken", highlightthickness=0)
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)

button_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

select_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="select")
pop_up_button = PopupSliderButton(button_frame, text="pop_up")

select_button.pack(side="left")
pop_up_button.pack(side="right")


text.insert("end", "line 3\nline 2\nline1")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]